# gstreamer videotestsrc state reset

Tags: python, gstreamer

I have a gstreamer pipeline with a videotestsrc. My plan is to change the pipeline, but without loosing the playback position of the videotestsrc. My current code changes the pipeline and changes the quarktv effect with the radioactv effect, but the videotestsrc starts from the beginning after resuming the pipeline. Is there a way to prevent that?

```
from gi.repository import Gst
import time
import os

os.environ["GST_DEBUG"] = "3"
Gst.init()
pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new()

def gen_cb(a, b, *c):
    print "gen_cb", a, b, c
    return Gst.PadProbeReturn.OK

# creating elements
vs = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videotestsrc')
vs.set_property('pattern', 18)
vs.set_property('is-live', 1)
pipeline.add(vs)

vc = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videoconvert')
pipeline.add(vc)

av = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autovideosink')
pipeline.add(av)

quark = Gst.ElementFactory.make('quarktv')
pipeline.add(quark)

radioactv = Gst.ElementFactory.make('radioactv')

q1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue')
pipeline.add(q1)

# linking
vs.link(q1)
q1.link(quark)
quark.link(vc)
vc.link(av)

# starting
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

# sleep some time
time.sleep(2)

# modify
probe_id = q1.pads[1].add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, gen_cb)
quark.unlink(q1)
pipeline.remove(quark)
quark.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
pipeline.add(radioactv)
q1.link(radioactv)
radioactv.link(vc)
radioactv.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
q1.pads[1].remove_probe(probe_id)

# wait until end
time.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, please file it in https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer

When you do modifications to the pipeline a 'reconfigure' event is generated so that elements adapt to a possible new configuration (a different format/resolution might be needed). As part of this it seems like videotestsrc is also resetting its internal state so the drawing restarts from '0'.